# How do you use a variable in the "replacement" part of query-replace-regexp?

Tags: variables, query-replace-regexp

I want to do simple replacements in a LaTeX source using something like that:

```
;; test-1
(query-replace-regexp (regexp-quote FOO)
                      (concat "Foo "
                              FOO
                              ".")
                      nil (point-min) (point-max))

;; test-2
(query-replace-regexp (regexp-quote VAR-1)
                      (concat "Foo "
                              VAR-2
                              ".")
                      nil (point-min) (point-max))
```

`FOO`, `VAR-1` and `VAR-2` could be everything and so I have to keep emacs from complaining about `Invalid use of ‘\\’ in replacement text`.

I have tried to use `regexp-quote` in the "replacement" part, but it doesn't always work because emacs sometimes complains about invalid use of `\\`.

I give my solutions here, but beyond whether the code works, I'm interested in understanding what is the correct way to use `FOO` and `VAR-2` in the second argument of `query-replace-regexp`.

For `test-1` I have two solutions:

```
(query-replace-regexp (concat "\\("
                              (regexp-quote FOO)
                              "\\)")
                      "Foo \\1." nil (point-min) (point-max))

(query-replace-regexp (regexp-quote FOO)
                      (concat "Foo "
                              (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\"
                                                        "\\\\\\\\"
                                                        (replace-regexp-in-string "\\["
                                                                                  "["
                                                                                  (replace-regexp-in-string "\\]"
                                                                                                            "]"
                                                                                                            FOO)))
                              ".")
                      nil (point-min) (point-max))
```

For `test2` I have one solution:

```
(query-replace-regexp (regexp-quote VAR-1)
                      (concat "Foo "
                              (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\"
                                                        "\\\\\\\\"
                                                        (replace-regexp-in-string "\\["
                                                                                  "["
                                                                                  (replace-regexp-in-string "\\]"
                                                                                                            "]"
                                                                                                            VAR-2)))
                              ".")
                      nil (point-min) (point-max))
```

These solutions seem very clunky to me, especially the one that resorts to using `replace-regexp-in-string`. I can't believe emacs doesn't allow you to do simple replacements like these, so for that I'd like to figure out the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, since you're replacing a fixed string by a fixed string, [use `query-replace` instead of `query-replace-regexp`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/75131).

In general, to replace a regexp by a fixed string, use `replace-quote` (missing from the manual).

```lisp
(replace-regexp my-regexp (replace-quote my-string))
```

Answer (score 2):

(Might as well make my comment an answer, I guess.  I can delete it if a reply indicates that it's not helpful.)

---

I don't understand the question. If you're always using `regexp-quote` on the first argument then I expect you should be using `query-replace` and not `query-replace-regexp`.

And in that case there's no worry about regexp patterns in the replacement text either -- nothing to escape. Have you tried just using `query-replace`?

Comment: I didn't know `query-replace`. I tried on some examples and it works great! It's the solution I was looking for!

Comment: Just FYI: you can accept an answer if you think it answers the question. That helps others who later have the same question and land here by googling, etc.